# Downloaded file is corrupted -Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbf)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, spring-boot, download

I have to trying download file which are in our system.FOr this I used spring boot and angular js 1.
The file is downloaded but is not open with message **Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbf)**.
My sample code is -

```
DownloadService.java


import com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Timed;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URLConnection;
@Component
@RequestMapping("/api/1/download")
@Path("/api/1/download")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Slf4j
public class DownloadResource {

 @ApiOperation(value = "downloads selected file", notes = "Returns a file", responseContainer = "FileSystemResource", response = HttpServletResponse.class)
 @Path("/downloadFile")
 @GET
 @Timed
 public void downloadFile(@Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  String filePath = ("/home/ashish/Desktop/CTA.jpg");
  File fileName = new File(filePath);
  String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName.getName());
  if (mimeType == null) {
   System.out.println("mimetype is not detectable, will take default");
   mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
  }
  response.setContentType(mimeType);
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline; filename=\"" + fileName.getName() + "\""));
  response.setContentLength((int) fileName.length());
  InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
  FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
  inputStream.close();

 }
}



download.js


app.controller('storeReportsCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, Restangular, $state, $stateParams, $location, $modal, $log, $timeout,$http,$sce) {
$scope.download = function(fileName) {

$http.get('/api/1/download/downloadFile', {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
             .success(function (response) {
               var a = document.createElement("a");
                   document.body.appendChild(a);
                   a.style = "display: none";
                   var fileName = "ppt2.jpg";
                  // var mimeType = data.mimeType;
                    var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'image/jpeg'}),
                     url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                       a.href = url;
                       a.download = fileName;
                       a.click();
                       window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
             }).catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
                 });
           }
});
```

From this file is downloaded but it is corrupted means my original file size is 18,394 bytes and response.byteLength = 33496.

**UPDATE**

Same code is working fine for text file but for binary file it not works.

How can I download correct file..

Comment: post update....

Answer (score 0):

String filePath = ("/home/ashish/Desktop/CTA.jpg");
filepath is a problem i think and make sure that file is exists

```
 @GetMapping("/downloadFile")
public void doima(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String filePath = ("\\home\\ashish\\Desktop\\CTA.jpg");
    File fileName = new File(filePath);     
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName.getName());
    System.out.println(mimeType);
    if (mimeType == null) {
        System.out.println("mimetype is not detectable, will take default");
        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline; filename=\"" + fileName.getName() + "\""));
    response.setContentLength((int) fileName.length());
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

CTA.jpg is present in your resource path then you can try 
like below

```
 InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("CTA.png");
```

Comment: file is at  ubuntu machine so I think path is like  /home/ashish/Desktop/CTA.jpg.On the"\\home\\ashish\\Desktop\\CTA.jpg" path it gives file not exist